# Compatibility of Lefschetz formula and categorical local Langlands correspondence

Tags: derived-categories, langlands-conjectures

Lefschetz-Verdied formula is formulated for etale sheaves and coherent sheaves in SGA 5 Ⅲ Theorem 4.4 for noetherian schemes.

My questions are that

1.Do we formulate the formula for objects and morphisms of derived (or stable ∞-category) of etale sheaves on Bun_G on Fargues-Fontaine curve? (or more generally small v-stacks)

2.Same question for objects and morphisms of bounded derived (or stable ∞-category) of coherent sheaves with compact supports on a scheme.

3.Do we write a cubic commutative diagram that consists of above two diagrams of Lefschetz-Verdier formula connecting via categorical local Langlands correspondence?

Thank you for your answer.